# Finding output voltage of a circuit containing diodes

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, conductive

I am given a circuit below and I was hoping to clear up some misunderstanding I may have about conducting and non-conducting diodes. I am not sure which part of my knowledge is wrong, although I know that something is wrong as I have gotten the following question wrong. Below is my working out, alongside the question:

I have found that the diode connected to the 2V will be conducting, to which the output voltage will be 2-0.7 = 1.3V.

I have come to the conclusion that this diode will be conducting because it means that it will stop the other diode connected to the 8V from conducting as 2V < 8V.

Whereas if it had been the diode connected to the 8V that was conducting, then the diode connected to the 2V would also conduct, leading to two different output voltages...

I appreciate any help,

thank you.

[image]

Comment: When a diode conducts, the anode is 0.7 V higher than the cathode. Reconsider the 1.3 V.

Comment: Assuming that D2 conducts: from where to where does the current flow? What is the voltage drop over the resistor?

Comment: So instead of 1.3, it would be 2.7?

Comment: Please use [mention feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to notify the person, else they won't notice if you're replying or not.

Comment: What is the anode voltage of D1? It should give you a clue to determine the cathode voltage as CL. already explained.